# Upload File jQuery ajax MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing application where I need to upload file ajax I used jQuery.form library but the action go to the controller with empty list of files I don't know why here is my code html:

```
<form id="well-log-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                <span>Well Logs</span>
                <input type="file" id="well-logs" class="upload" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

and Js Code is :

```
   document.getElementById("well-logs").onchange = function () {

    var _url = "/Importer/WellLogUpload";
    var options = {         
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,  

        url: _url,
        type: 'post'        

    };
    $('#well-log-form').ajaxSubmit(options);
};
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    return true;
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
   // $("body").append(responseText);
}
```

could any one help, I think it should work but I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in jquery, it will post your file.

```
//#file is the id of { <input type="file" id="file"> }

$("#file").change(function () {

    var file_data = $(this).prop("files")[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", file_data)

    $.ajax({
        url: "your url",
        type: "post",
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (path) {
           //on success
        }
    });

});
```